# How to print only the first three comments from the website through System.out.println method using Selenium Webdriver and Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, webdriver

I need to print the first three reviews from a website; specifically, this one: https://www.yelp.com/biz/golden-boy-pizza-san-francisco?osq=Restaurants+Pizza

This is my selector:

```
$$('div.review-content p')
```

That selector shows the 20 texts that exist within the 20 visible reviews. I need only to print the first three (0, 1, 2) texts in my code. I don't have a method yet though. To summarize, my question would be: if I declared a list that holds all those elements with the selector I mentioned, how can I print the first three elements from that list and then stop? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Xpath has been used to location the review texts in following example, however you can use any other locator as well.

```
List<WebElement> reviewTexts = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='review-content']//p"));
        int i=1;
        for (WebElement reviewText : reviewTexts) {

            System.out.println("Review text " + i + ": " + reviewText.getText());
            i++;

            if (i>3) {
                break;
            }

        }
```

Try above code and let me know whether it works for you.

Comment: This works quite well, but it was not well received within my circle since it forces the condition before the for and they wanted the condition to stop inside the for. Still, thanks! This gave me a good insight on how to use the for.

Answer (score 0):

As per your question to extract only the first three review texts you can induce *WebDriverWait* first to create a *List* and print the desired number of *reviews* and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
  driver.get("https://www.yelp.com/biz/golden-boy-pizza-san-francisco?osq=Restaurants+Pizza");
  List<WebElement> myList = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector("div.review-content p")));
  for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
      System.out.println(myList.get(i).getAttribute("innerHTML"));
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  When I visited earlier this year, it's more like the pizza visited my very being. It may have taken over a bit, lol. It was and is the best focaccia pizza I have had on the West coast so far, at the very least. Probably the best pizza overall too. There are some close seconds, with different styles, etc of course. Pizza is a very picky, moody and delicate situation. <br><br>I would recommend the garlic slice. Wow. Then the pepperoni. The pesto one was not amazing, but I generally don't like pesto versions of pizza anyway, so thats my pickiness, not so much the place itself.
  Square slice focaccia pizza? Yes please!<br><br>I almost always end up here whenever I'm in the area. Even when I'm not in the area I seem to end up here. My go-to definitely has to be their garlic clam slice, plenty of clams, garlicky goodness, melted cheese, all on top of a fluffy focaccia with a crispy bottom. My boyfriend usually gets the pepperoni or sausage slice and we split a combo slice on top of that, super satisfying. <br><br>Unless you're coming here for late night drunchies, highly recommend coming in the afternoon if you don't want to wait in a long line as it gets pretty crowded at night.
  I ate a slice of combo pizza, which was amazing!<br>I liked how fluffy it was. &nbsp;Limited seating at the restaurant.<br>Bought a slice of Pesto &amp; veggie to go.<br>I was surprised that they did not want to sell me a small box for the slice, even though I requested for it and I agreed to pay the extra 50 cents...weird.
  ```

Comment: Yes! This is actually what I wanted. Thank you very much!